# How to reference css and .js files with absolute urls

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, less

i'm trying to reference a js file and stylesheet using an absolute url. Doesn't seem to work. The reason i need to use an absolute url is because the css file is not editable if i use ~. This is what i have, my stylesheet is not applied and seems like its not found...

`<script src="D:/MyProjects/myProject/Src/Web/Scripts/less-1.3.0-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="D:/MyProjects/myProject/Src/Web/Content/CSS/mystylesheet.less" />
```

Comment: what you are actually trying to do with this ?
"the css file is not editable if i use ~."
what does it means ???

Answer (score 3):

That's not an absolute path that's a physical path. An absolute path would be something like `http://localhost/Content/CSS/mystylesheet.less`

Comment: thanks, why would my physical path not work? and would the above absolute path work in an mvc app? @Karthikeyan - what i mean by not editable....i want to edit my less file and reload the page and see my changes come into effect, this doesnt seem to work with a relative path.

Comment: You may have your JS and CSS on "D:/MyProject...", but if you deploy/upload your application on a server other browser clients don´t have these files on their system. That´s why you have to put an relative path - in MVC "Url.Content("~/Content/YOURFILE.js") and upload everything to your server.